# .NET MAUI View does not render properly a List

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mobile, maui

I am new to the **.NET MAUI** ecosystem and I am developing an app following the MVVM pattern, I got a **viewmodel binded to a certain view**. I got a **custom model MyCustomModel** with a bunch of public string properties, inside my viewmodel I got a list of MyCustomModel objects so something like **List<MyCustomModel> CustomList** on this list attribute in my viewmodel the *PropertyChanged methods are all implemented*. I got a view that should display the elements inside CustomList and the view is something like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Containers}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="10">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Container_Number}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Container_Quantity}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Item_Description}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**The CustomList inside the viewmodel gets updated dynamically trough a function that appends via the CustomList.Add(new element of MyCustomModel) a new object to the list**. The strange thing is happening to me is that if CustomList has only 1 element so CustomList.Count == 1 then the xaml in the view displays the info correctly (so in this case where the view works I just add one element manually and thats it, there is no dynamical update of CustomList in a method) but as soon as the Add method adds new object dynamically via a function so Custom.Count is no more == 1 but > 1 then the page is blank the view does not render propery the data.

I am sure the problem is inside the view because debugging and doing some System.Console.Write I saw that CustomList.Count gets incremented each time that function is invoked and also the info inside CustomList are stored correctly so why this strange behaviour?

Comment: Please show the code where the `Containers` list is defined and how you update it. When adding items to a list that is used in data binding, any update needs to be propagated via a *PropertyChanged* notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to [data binding in MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/data-binding-basics#bindings-and-collections) and [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm).

You can use an `ObservableCollection<MyCustomModel>` instead of `List<MyCustomModel>`. Any changes to the collection should then be reflected in your UI.

The problem likely is that your *List* is not observable and you're not triggering any *PropertyChanged* events for it. *ObservableCollection* handles this for you.